# Qt Resource Not Working

Tags: c++, qt

I've seen every SE question and have even followed some video tutorials. I have no idea why it isn't working.

I have two QLabels, `lblBuyer` and `lblSeller` as well as two pictures. Here is the relevant code:

```
QPixmap pixmap_buyer(":/Resources/Images/Buyer.png"), pixmap_seller(":/Resources/Images/Seller.png");

size_t lblBuyerWidth = ui->lblBuyer->width(), lblBuyerHeight = ui->lblBuyer->height();
size_t lblSellerWidth = ui->lblSeller->width(), lblSellerHeight = ui->lblSeller->height();

ui->lblBuyer->setPixmap(
    pixmap_buyer.scaled(lblBuyerWidth, lblBuyerHeight, Qt::KeepAspectRatio)
);

ui->lblSeller->setPixmap(
    pixmap_seller.scaled(lblSellerWidth, lblSellerHeight, Qt::KeepAspectRatio)
);
```

This is what the resources look like:

[image]

And the resources.qrc if you want it:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/Resources">
        <file>Images/Buyer.png</file>
        <file>Images/Seller.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

And the file structure (images are directly in the Images directory):
[image]

I selected "Copy as Resource Path" so I was sure not to mess anything up. Also, when I click "Remove Missing Files," neither gets removed... However, when I run it:

```
QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap
QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap
```

Comment: What does `pixmap_buyer.isNull()` return? What if you try opening the files in the resources using `QFile` instead (just for checking whether the file is indeed in the resource system).

Comment: It returns true. I did an `if(...isNull()) qDebug("Is null");` and it does print.

Answer (score 3):

I have seen this a couple of times, and the cure varies:

The first thing to try is **clean**/**rebuild** your project.

The second thing to try is to **manually clean**/**rebuild** your project (as in delete your build dir by hand in a file manager).

If the problem still persists, you can try **putting a resource init macro into main**.

In other words, put a line like: `Q_INIT_RESOURCE(my_resource);` in your `main()` function just after instantiating your app for each resource in your project, like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Q_INIT_RESOURCE(my_resource);
    // ... whatever here ...
    return app.exec();}
}
```

Of course you put the name of your actual resource file in place of `my_resource`.

This is usually necessary only when I am doing some strange stuff like using my own static Qt or using a wired project structure.

Comment: The `Q_INIT_RESOURCE` definition is not working, but clearing out the build directory and re-building did the job. Thanks. Apparently I'm supposed to add `-name` to the makefile compile string?

Comment: @Goodies: I restructured my answer and I hope it is better now!